# Site for mobile phone display

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-phones

Here i need to create a site that should support all Internet accessible mobiles.
May i use javascript, in Some forum they told that javascript doesn't work's in mobile phones.

Suggest me clear, In mobile phone javascript work or not ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The level of JavaScript support in mobile phones varies greatly. I use [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/index.php) to determine the device's capabilities before deciding what HTML and JavaScript to return to the device. WURFL is a large device capabilities database formatted as XML. It's opensource so you can include it in your own application. Take a look at this other [WURFL site](http://www.wurflpro.com/) to query a specific device and see what information WURL can provide for you.